# Processing text in csv document

Tags: python, csv, text-processing

I'm starting some text analysis on some csv documents. However my csv document has several sentences with few words which do not interest me, so I wanted to create a python code that analyzed this csv document and left only the sentences that contain more than 5 words for my analysis, however I do not I know where to start making my code and would like some help.

example:

Input document
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcBoA.jpg)

Output document
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp0zP.jpg)

Comment: Google for "python csv tutorial" - you will learn about the `csv` module and how to load the contents of the csv file into your program. Once that is done, then you will be able to filter out those rows that do not meet whatever criteria you set up.

Comment: Maybe start by putting an example of your input data and the output you would like to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (with Python 3.5):

```
lines = []
finalLines = []
toRemove = ['a', 'in', 'the']

with open('export.csv') as f:
    lines.append(f.readlines())

for line in lines:
    temp = list(csv.reader(line))
    sentence = ''
    for word in temp[0][0].split():
        if (word not in toRemove):
            sentence = sentence + ' ' + word
    finalLines.append(sentence.strip())

print(finalLines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your work done efficiently and with ease if you use pandas (python library widely used for data manipulation). Here is the link for official pandas documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Note: Pandas has built-in functions for reading csv files. You can use 'skiprow' parameter to skiprows you dont want or apply regex to filter text.